# how to refresh table after adding a new item in asp.net mvc 3 razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to asp.net mvc and struggling to find the right way to refresh the table after a new item is added to the list of items that table displays.

The Add new item controls are on the same page as the list. So, when the user clicks "Add", I want to add it to the database and display the refreshed list in the table below. While I have the controller working to add it to the DB, I'm unable to refresh the list. Could you please let me the know the way to refresh the table in this scenario?

Here is my view -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="txtAddName" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnAdd"  onclick="Add(); return false;">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="txtName-@m.Id.ToString()" type="text" value="@m.Name.ToString()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

function Add() {
        var _Name = $("#txtAddName").val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")';
        $.post(
        url,
        {
            Name: _Name
        },
        function (data) {

        });
    }
```

Controller -

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult Create(string name)
    {
        // Logic to add item goes here


        // What do I return here? I would want my table to now display the refreshed (including the new item)
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        // List is the action method that returns the initial list, both these are in the same controller
        return View(data);
    }
```

Comment: please check "Update 2" on my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change **Controller** Like below **:**

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult Create(string name)
    {
      // Logic to add item goes here

     // What do I return here? I would want my table to now display the refreshed (including the new item)

      return RedirectToAction("List");//redirect to List Action Method
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        // List is the action method that returns the initial list, both these are in the same controller
        return View(data);
    }
```

***Note :*** Inside the Above **List action method**, you have to **take latest data from database** and **send back to View.**

**Latest Update :**

Here I am giving how to show **table with a list of items which are coming from controller**.

Try to use this kind of view in your application to show your content.

```
           <div class="boxedForm">
                    <table id="productDetails">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">
                                UPC Code
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @ foreach (var p in Model.ProductList)
                           {
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td>
                                @p.ProductName
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @p.UpcCode
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
            </div>
```

***My ViewModel is like***

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
       public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
    }
```

***My Model is like***

```
public class Product
    {
        public Product() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); Created = DateTime.Now; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string UpcCode { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update 2 :**

***Try to use your post method like below:***

```
function Add() {
        var _Name = $("#txtAddName").val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Item")';
        $.post(
        url,
        {
            Name: _Name
        },
        function (data) {
            var url = Sys.Url.route('YourRouteName', { action: "List", controller: "YourControllerName"});
            window.location = url;  
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've done that already, but my View is unable to use this data coming back because of the way it is setup. Could you please provide me some direction on how I can re-load my table in the view with this data? I'm very new to JQuery and cannot seem to understand how these things work.

Comment: inside the List method you have to call your repository(data base call) and then fill your model/viewmodel(in your case it is data) from that data and send back to UI.What is your exact issue?

Comment: I've figured out how to pass back the data from the Controller and now  my issue is to refresh the table in the view with the new row appended at the bottom. How do I do it?

Comment: can you put small image or something that kind of mock up to look up the way you want to show your data.i.e:The final out put of your view with data ?.

Comment: I've provided html in my question. Let me try to explain here again... I have a text box and the corresponding button "Add" and below these items, there is a html table that has all the list of items. When the user clicks Add, I need to add this new item to my DB list of items and update the table below to include the new item. Does this help?

Comment: Hi Sampath, Thanks for your patience. But, it still doesn't work. I've changed my controlled to have the code exactly like you suggested above. I get a feeling that it may be because of the way I'm doing the "post". Can you please check in my code (Add javascript function) above to see if I have that right? I guess I'm missing something there?

Comment: what is happening? when you do post is it add data to the database?Then what is happening is it go to List method?Is it fill with latest data ? check those things with vs debugger and let me know?

Comment: Yes, it's added to the database. It's going to the list method and filling with the latest data. However, when I look at the "data", in my $.post response, I see it has all the HTML and I'm not sure how I can process the data in that success method in jQuery's post.